How Can I Find an Eclipse RCP View by its ID?
I am working on getting into Eclipse RCP development. Since I've already chewed through all tutorials out there, I'm now trying to build an IDE by peeking into another large, sophisticated, but undocumented RCP product whose source code I have and copying things one by one.
I want to add the Project Explorer to my default perspective. I copied the following view into my plugin.xmls perspectiveExtension tag:
<view
        id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"
        minimized="false"
        ratio="0.25"
        relationship="left"
        relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss">
</view>

and it does not show up in my product. If I replace the id with "org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" or "org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline", those views show up. It also works in the example product (I copy-pasted it). I gather that the Project Explorer is in some other dependency plugin, which the example product has, but I don't. Now here's where I'm stuck: I cannot find out which plugin I need to add in order to have this view available. In fact, I can't find any information at all about the org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer view.
I recently discovered the "Navigate" > "Open Type" command, which has been pretty handy,
but org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer is an ID, not a class name, so nothing shows up.
Google search turns up nothing except a similarly-named class org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer in an archived version of the standard Eclipse docs. No SO posts, no tutorials, nothing.
To be clear: my question is not about how to use the Project Explorer specifically, but how I can get information about unknown views and components in general, given only an ID or similar information.
EDIT: okay, I found it via the docs under "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide" > "Common Navigator Framework". Still, not every view and plugin happens to have a whole instructions section dedicated to it, so my question of how to resolve an ID is still open. It's not like this is the first time I've had a hard time finding RCP objects.

What you are looking it as an extension contributing a view to an existing perspective when what you're looking for is the extension declaring the view itself: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_views.html?cp=2_1_1_210
Open the Search dialog and use the Plug-in Search tab to search for References to that Extension Point--the Extensions. That should let you find where the actual Project Explorer view is declared and where the class for it lives (assuming it is somewhere in your Target Platform).

Okay, that's a handy function, thanks for pointing that out. But what do I search? org.eclipse.ui.views? That's a lot of results.

@LemongrabThree Yes, you search on the extension point, the plug-in id containing the extension point usually lets to narrow down which ones to look at. You can also use the Eclipse "Plug-in Selection Spy" (⌥+⌘+F1 on macOS, not sure about other OSs) on any window to show the class providing the window.
