How to access the Eclipse Servers plugin from my plugin
I'm writing an Eclipse plugin in Java. I'd like to be able to access the Servers plugin (that comes with the Eclipse Java EE version). For example, I'm hoping I can trigger the Start or Terminate buttons from my plugin.
I found this answer:
Getting the content of a view Eclipse RCP
In order to make it work, I need to know:
Where do I find the ID for the Servers view?
What plugin/package do I need to import?
What implementation of IViewPart do I cast too?
And then I can hope that they provided some public methods that I can call that do what I want.
EDIT:
The Plugin Selection Spy provided some helpful information-- I know the relevant classes and packages now. If I could get access the TreeSelection class and the Server objects, I think I can do what I want. Unfortunately, ServersView2 doesn't seem to provide any public access to the TreeSelection...

What problem does triggering the Start or Terminate buttons from your plugin solve? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78299393/how-can-i-find-an-eclipse-rcp-view-by-its-id/78299620

Invoking Eclipse Plugin Selection Spy on a view shows at lot of information about it - Alt+Shift+F1 (⌥+Shift+F1 on macOS)

My plugin runs a series of tasks, some of which will fail if the server is running.

Why would they fail?

They need to modify/delete files in use by the server. Also, the server configuration files are updated, so it will need to be restarted.

Ok, but digging deeper again, why? What are the modifications, and what are they for?

You can skip dealing with the plugin-- to get access to the server instances in eclipse, use ServerCore:
https://eclipse.dev/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/ServerCore.html#getServers()
